# Get data from fragment to activity with button in the activity

Tags: android

my android app main activity contains 3 fragments.The main activity also contain two buttons-save and cancel.The fragments contain EditTexts .i want to take data from these EditTexts and Spinner upon Save button click event(Event occur in parent activity).Is it Possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define public method to get `EditText` text value inside your fragment and call it in your activity

SomeFragment.java:

```
public String getText() {
    return editText.getText().toString();
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
SomeFragment fragment1;
Button btn_save;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    // fragment1 = get instance of your fragment

    btn_save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_save);
    btn_save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            fragment1.getText();
        }
    });
}
```